# How to create circular bevel?

Tags: modifiers

I would like to use a non-destructive method to bevel two edges to follow a circular profile, like so:

[image: circular edge]

I tried to apply a bevel modifier, but I'm even more confused because setting the red edge to a 1.0 bevel weight affected the other bevel. Does Blender limit the bevel amount to the lowest applicable value?

[image]

Here is the blend file:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: it doesn't seem possible so instead maybe use a cylinder as boolean to dig your shape

Comment: The interaction between the bevels is probably due  to _Clamp Overlap_

Comment: @RobinBetts thank you, disabling "clamp overlap" does not modify the first bevel anymore

Comment: but does it give the desired result?

Comment: @moonboots no, it gives more an appearance of an ellipse used as boolean instead of a cylinder